# JavaFX Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: javafx

I got this error running my program to other Device. It works fine on my computer where I originally written the code.

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules hamcrest.core and junit export package org.hamcrest.internal to module json.simple
```

Configured the Module-info but didn't work.

Comment: hamcrest and junit are test frameworks.  It is unlikely they should be in code exported to your [runtime image](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular).

Comment: What version of Java are you using on your computer? What's the version on the other computer? What version of hamcrest and junit are you using? How are you building and running the application? What does your `module-info.java` file look like? Please [edit] your question to provide more details and a [mre] if possible.

Comment: `json-simple`, if it is [this library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple) appears to be ancient and unmaintained.  Old libraries sometimes won't function correctly in a modern modular Java environment.  I would advise a better-maintained json library based on Java modules, of which there are numerous ones for Java (e.g. [gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [jakarta json](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/jsonp/2.1/apidocs/)) and [example tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json).

Comment: What Java version is running on your device, on the other device, in your application?